# Не применяется media запросы

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Такая беда: решил создать адаптивный шаблон для себя, но столкнулся с такой проблемой не применяется медиа запросы, медиа запрос стоит после основных стилей, проверял в хроме и в яндексе даже в песочнице.

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.conteiner {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*height: 1000px;*/
}

.content {
  width: 66.66666666666667%;
  background-color: inherit;
  float: right;
}

.side {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100px;*/
  background-color: #cc0;
}

@media screen and(max-width: 480px) {
  .content,
  .side {
    float: none;
  }
  .content {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">

  <div class="side">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima explicabo quis rerum facere veritatis exercitationem quia quas quaerat impedit molestiae quidem laborum porro nam optio praesentium ipsam amet, quo error!</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis velit mollitia, voluptas minus rem, nesciunt, ducimus at aperiam reprehenderit eos aspernatur. Hic, nobis corrupti totam veniam libero nesciunt vel enim!</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="footer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, facilis, quam. At esse magnam molestiae. Nihil, dolorum. Eveniet possimus iusto, esse suscipit soluta sint obcaecati aspernatur hic harum dolor, fugiat!</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заработало, всего-навсего нужно добавить пробел: `and (max-width: 480px)`

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.conteiner {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  width: 66.66666666666667%;
  background-color: inherit;
  float: right;
}

.side {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cc0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .content,
  .side {
    float: none;
  }
  .content {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">

  <div class="side">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima explicabo quis rerum facere veritatis exercitationem quia quas quaerat impedit molestiae quidem laborum porro nam optio praesentium ipsam amet, quo error!</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis velit mollitia, voluptas minus rem, nesciunt, ducimus at aperiam reprehenderit eos aspernatur. Hic, nobis corrupti totam veniam libero nesciunt vel enim!</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="footer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, facilis, quam. At esse magnam molestiae. Nihil, dolorum. Eveniet possimus iusto, esse suscipit soluta sint obcaecati aspernatur hic harum dolor, fugiat!</div>

</div>
```

*P.S. Правда, не знаю честно говоря что такое получилось :D*

---

Пример с пробелом:

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Тот же пример, но без пробела:

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and(max-width: 750px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```